# jQuery loop one to one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have problem with my code.

I have products on my website, each product has his own `<a><h1>CODE</h1></a>` and I need to take this CODE and paste it before an image. I need to copy element with has `class="loop1"` and paste it into another element with `class="lop1"` and then take another element with `class="loop2"` and paste into element with `class="lop2"` and so on..

I made class with same numbers for easier copying, but it doesnt work. Can sombody help me?

This is my code:

```
$('#loop').addClass(function(i) {
   return 'lop'+(i+1);
    });
$('.p-name').addClass(function(i) {
   return 'loop'+(i+1);
    });

    function doForm() {
        var numb = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","13","14"];

        for (var i=0;i<numb.length;i++) { 
            number = numb[i];

            selector = '.loop' + number;


                if ($(selector).length != 0) {
                val = $(selector).html();
                $('lop' + number).html(val);
            }
        }
    }

    doForm();
```

Related html:

```
<div class="columns">
    <div id="loop" class="lop1"></div>
       <div class="p-image">
         <a href="/"><img src="https://" width="290" height="218"></a>
       </div>

     <div class="p-info">
        <a href="/" title="PRODUCT" class="p-name loop1" itemprop="url" style="height: 80px;"><span itemprop="name">PRODUCT</span></a>
      </div>
<div>
```

So I need to take from "`p-info > a`" and paste it into div "`lop1`". Depends on number in class copy and paste HTML into div with same number.

Comment: Hard to understand what you're asking here. Need to edit your question and add more details.

Comment: It would be helpful if the related html was here as well.

Comment: ...and what is radek?

Comment: sorry "radek" is numb

Comment: Share your HTML code.

Comment: When is this code being executed? Is that after the page has loaded?

Comment: Change `$('lop' + radek).html(val);` to `$('.lop' + number).html(val);`

Comment: Sorry it is just translate mistake, the code is OK. 

 And YES code is executed after page is loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `$('lop' + radek).html(val);` to `$('.lop' + number).html(val);`
Notice the `.` at the beginning of `lop`, it will create a selector to fetch element based on the class.

```js
$('#loop').addClass(function(i) {
   return 'lop'+(i+1);
});
$('.p-name').addClass(function(i) {
   return 'loop'+(i+1);
});

function doForm() {
    var numb = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","13","14"];
    for (var i=0;i<numb.length;i++) { 
        var number = numb[i];
        var selector = '.loop' + number;
        if ($(selector).length != 0) {
            var val = $(selector).html();
            $('.lop' + number).html(val);
        }
    }
}

doForm();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="columns">
    <div id="loop" class="lop1"></div>
       <div class="p-image">
         <a href="/"><img src="https://" width="290" height="218"></a>
       </div>

     <div class="p-info">
        <a href="/" title="PRODUCT" class="p-name loop1" itemprop="url" style="height: 80px;"><span itemprop="name">PRODUCT</span></a>
      </div>
<div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help the dot before class lop was mistake :)